# Trigger a cloud watch Alarm when an ECS service continually restarts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to trigger an Alarm and send out a notification using Cloudwatch and SNS to detect when an ECS Task keeps getting restarted.
Can someone suggest the better approach?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking for a better approach between the two - Clodwatch and SNS.
But,

Both CloudWatch and SNS (Simple Notification Service) play different roles in monitoring and notifying about ECS (Amazon Elastic Container Service) Task restarts. The better approach would be to use them together as they serve complementary purposes:

**CloudWatch** is primarily used for monitoring and collecting metrics from various AWS resources. It allows you to set up alarms based on these metrics and define actions when the alarms are triggered. In your case, you can use CloudWatch to monitor the ECS Task's restart count metric and set up an alarm based on that.

**SNS** is a notification service that enables you to send messages or notifications to multiple endpoints (such as email, SMS, Lambda, etc.) when certain events occur. In this case, you can create an SNS topic to which the CloudWatch alarm will publish a notification when triggered.

By using both CloudWatch and SNS together, you get the benefit of CloudWatch's robust monitoring capabilities and SNS's flexible notification system. When the ECS Task restarts cross the defined threshold, the CloudWatch alarm will be triggered, and it will automatically publish a notification to the configured SNS topic. The notification will then be sent to all the subscribed endpoints, allowing you to be promptly informed about the frequent task restarts.

You can follow these steps -

- Create a custom metric to track the number of task restarts (you'll
  need to push this metric to CloudWatch from your ECS environment).
- Set up an alarm in CloudWatch that monitors this custom metric.
  Define the threshold at which you want the alarm to trigger (e.g., if
  the task restarts more than X times within Y minutes).
- Define an action for the alarm, which will be an SNS topic.
- Create an SNS topic to handle ECS Task restart notifications.
- Subscribe to this SNS topic with the preferred endpoints where you
  want to receive the notifications (e.g., email, SMS, etc.).